# Using jsoup to find element on webpage

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to get the name of the captain in string format from the below page. In this case it would be Kane

http://fantasy.premierleague.com/entry/390/event-history/30/

I am using Jsoup and whatever I try it is not working, just a blank string. If anyone has any suggestions on how to do this it would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: "whatever I try it is not working" can we see your code? Also how is captain marked in that page? Where in HTML code of this page we can find this information?

Comment: To improve your question and put some additional informations you can use [edit] option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div.ismPlayerContainer:has(img.ismCaptainOn) span.JS_ISM_NAME
```

This css selector will return the span with the name of the Captain.

You can check here: [Jsoup](http://try.jsoup.org/~rD0NTm2SPcZu-ivYXWpjHvdDErA)

Now its just return the text of the element that you'll have after you run this css selector against the document.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The above worked. Thank you very much. my code is below

String url2 = "http://fantasy.premierleague.com/entry/390/event-history/30/";
    Document document2 = Jsoup.connect(url2).get();

Elements elements = document2.select("div.ismPlayerContainer:has(img.ismCaptainOn) span.JS_ISM_NAME");
  System.out.println(elements.text());